# Does anyone know the name of this connector?

Tags: connector, cables

I have a device that is power by this cable. Now the cable became faulty and I want to replace it. Does anyone know its name? It looks like a 2-pin LED connector, but it is sightly different.

[image: Cable]

Comment: A side view of the connector, and some information on the device it is used on, may be helpful. Conxall and Switchcraft (and no doubt many other makers) produce connectors similar to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the type of connector you're looking for, and it can be purchased [here](http://www.adorama.com/ajptapcbl.html) and on eBay [here](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=D5%2F10-PC&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=D5%2F10-PC%20Connector&_sacat=0) for around the same price. It's called a D5/10-PC connector.

Comment: wow nice work! +1

Answer (score -2):

It is very likely a DIN connector: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector

Or an XLR connector (a.k.a. Cannon plug): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLR_connector

Comment: It is definitely not an XLR connector.